# For loop with events

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working with along with an online tutorial and trying to understand the code below. What I don't get is why this works more than two times. When the loop has been executed two times `i == len` and the condition `i < len` isn't true anymore. So how come it's possible to toggle the different classes more than two times?

My guess is that when the condition is false `i` gets set to `0` again, did I understand that correctly? Hope someone can help me, I didn't find an explanation of this particular problem anywhere online.

**HTML**

```
 <button>Normal</button>
 <button>Changed</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.normal {background-color: white;color:black;}
.changed {background-color: black;color:white;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i +=1)
  buttons[i].onclick = function() {
    var className = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    document.body.className = className;
 }}
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop gets excecuted only once and iterates through all buttons.
In the `for` loops body, you define an `onclick` function for each button.

So, before you can click anywhere the loop already has finished, and added an `onclick` function to each single button, which will be called everytime, you click on that button.

With `button[i].onclick = function() {...}` you add an event handler function to the buttons click event.

You should read more about [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) in general.